# Dysfunctional desktop

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, desktop

I'm having problems with the behaviour of the Ubuntu 22.04 desktop. I don't know why, the block button stopped working. I mean the "lock" icon key in the Logitech MX Keys. I think it stopped working after the latest update of the NVIDIA drivers or something I did with Citrix or GNOME Shell. Moreover, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>) changed behaviour too. The default Ubuntu screen is lost (the all-gray screen with the credentials in the center). Now I see a black screen with the ugly terminal in the upper left corner saying `Ubuntu 22.04.02 cesarkero-pc tty1` etc.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> I go back to the normal desktop.

If I block the user pushing here, the user is blocked and you go to a GNOME style different from the default, with a purple screen, with the login at the left side and with an icon that allows you to select between different desktop styles.

[image]

The main problem with this screen is that, even if I have my PC configured to never suspend, if the user is locked, the PC is suspended anyway. The default locking screen in Ubuntu didn't behave that way. It was as easy as pushing the lock button in the keyboard and go.

I have reinstalled everything (NVIDIA drivers included) and every reverted to the default desktop configuration [as described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413294/lost-appearance-ubuntu-22-04-lts-original).

The shutdown button stopped working too, even with this configuration:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but purging and reinstalling solved the thing:

```
apt purge gnome-shell
apt purge ubuntu-desktop
apt autoremove -y
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```